# Could not load type in C#

Tags: c#

In my C# class that was working well and suddenly from yesterday when I try to run the program I get the following error. When I try to Build the solution it is building sucessfully.

> ```
> Could not load type 'FileNet.Api.Admin.IRepository' from
> ```
>
> assembly 'FileNet.Api,
>   Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=63fc2fb3fdeef4f1'.

When I try to debug the solution, I get the above error at the SetOSNames(); I am not able to step into SetOSNames(); method.

Please help

```
private void IntializeVariables(IConnection connection)
{
    domain = Factory.Domain.FetchInstance(connection, null, null);
    domainName = domain.Name;
    ost = domain.ObjectStores;
    SetOSNames(); ///Error thrown here
}

//
// Intializes the ArrayList osNames with object store names.
//
public void SetOSNames()
{
    IEnumerator ie = ost.GetEnumerator();
    while (ie.MoveNext())
    {
        IObjectStore os = (IObjectStore)ie.Current;
        osNames.Add(os.DisplayName);
    }
}
```

Comment: The exception seems pretty self explanatory. You are trying to load the `FileNet.Api.Admin.IRepository` type which doesn't exist in the `FileNet.Api, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=63fc2fb3fdeef4f1` assembly.

Comment: You posted the wrong code. What we needed to see was the place in `FileNet.Api.Admin` where you define the `IRepository` type. (hint, hint)

Comment: In addition to the previous comments: Code only suddenly stops working due to changes made before it. Find out what you changed, and revert it step by step, or if you working with source control, get a previous version.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The compiler is happy with your code, which indicates that the reference assembly does not match the assembly that's found at runtime.  Use the Fuslogvw.exe tool to find out what assembly is getting loaded.  Be sure to log all the binds, not just the failed ones.  The odds are good that it is finding the wrong version of FileNet.Api.dll, possibly because an old version is stored in the GAC.  Avoid using the GAC on your dev machine.

Comment: You are absolutely correct. GAC was the issue. Thank you very much